# Jersey Java Webservice XML

Tags: java, web-services, xml-serialization, jersey

I've built up a Webservice in Java using Jersey.
The Webservice consumes XML and takes a POJO (CoResponse) as MethodParameters.

I.E.

```
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public CoResponse test(CoResponse obj){
        //...do something....
        return obj;
    }
```

On Client side I would do a Put Request like this...

```
CoResponse rO = service.path("path")
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .put(CoResponse.class, new CoResponse());
```

Actually everything is working fine in our environment. But now I would like to know what the xml-string sent to the Server looks like. The reason why is to use the webservice also in other environments by creating a custom Serializer / Deserializer (i.e. for windows mobile) that is compatible to our jersey webservice.

Is there a way of looking into the put method to see the final xmlstring? Or some other possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [LoggingFilter](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/LoggingFilter.html).
Just add it to your client:

```
client.add(new LoggingFilter(System.out));
```